# iOS Swift Animation does not work some times

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Cant solve problem of showing animation in custom popup.
In my app i use SwiftEntryKit to show top alert with custom view. This custom view contains animation

```
        UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.8,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: [.autoreverse, .repeat],
        animations:
        {
            let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.img.transform = scale
    }, completion: nil)
```

Everything works as expected, i can show a popup with scale animation.

But when i call exactly same popup after network call with RxSwift animation does not work. No errors no info, view just gets it scaled up 1.3 size and does not show animation. Here is part of my code with networking

```
        HelperAuth.makeRegister(name: name!, email: email!, password: password!)
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext:
            { reponse in

                print(reponse)
        }, onError:
            { error in
                MessagesManager.showRedAlerter(text: "ERRRRAR")//here is my method to show popup with animation
        }).disposed(by: coordinatorAuth.disposeBag)
```

Cant find any reason of this strange behavior.

Comment: in RxSwift use the code like this:  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.animatableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.animatableView.frame = self.animatableView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 50, dy: 0)
            }, completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    self.animatableView.alpha = 0
                })
            })
        })

Comment: Dhaval thanks for answer, i do not understand how it works but yes, now my animation works as it should in normal mode and after Rx call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dhaval Raval mentioned in comments wraping animation in completing block of other animation solves animation problem.

I changed my code of animation to

```
        UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 0.0,
        animations: {
    }, completion:
        { _ in
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.8,
                delay: 0.0,
                options: [.autoreverse, .repeat],
                animations:
                {
                    let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                    self.img.transform = scale
            }, completion: nil)
    })
```

and now it works as it should and from normal method call and after RxSwift Networking call